# Sitecore default language for creating items

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, sitecore6

How to change the default language for new items in sitecore? Changing the <setting name="DefaultLanguage" value="fr" /> didn't work as far as Sitecore still is adding item with "en" as default version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems a bit simplistic of an answer, but I think this isn't so much a global setting as it is something that is more flexible and user-centric.  I believe that Sitecore will add new items based on the current language version that you're using.  For example, if you're looking at the French version of an item.  The next time you create an item... of any type, it's going to create a French version of the item.

Also, when you said default language, I'm assuming that you're talking about the default language setting.  You can also specify a language setting in the site declaration as well.. if that helps.

Comment: With the exception of bucket item parent folders. They are always in english apparantly.